# JavaScript on python to calculate s2 cell from given lat lon for 3 million records

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, python-2.7, geomap

I'm after calculating s2 cell from given Lat and Lon, I am new to python and JavaScript, fiddle around the net and found Javascript code on URL https://npm.runkit.com/s2-geometry.
I have a csv file with two fields: lat and lot with 3 million records and want to add the s2 cell to the given data.

I have found code which gives result in decimal, also need to add function to convert the result in hexadecimal.

```
    var s2Geometry = require("s2-geometry").S2;
    var lat = -33.804115;
    var lng = 150.992465;
    var level = 18;
    var key = s2Geometry.latLngToKey(lat, lng, level);
    var id = s2Geometry.keyToId(key);
```

not sure how to modify the script to get the csv file in python, modify the script for the desired result, I am new to python and JavaScript, why Python: coz I have access to python and R.

Expected result - three column in csv (Lat lon s2cell)